# MySQL: bulk sending 20000 SELECT query from c#

Tags: c#, mysql, database, query-string

I have to make a very simple select where only the parameter change. But I have to repeat it for a huge number of keywords.

i.e.

```
SELECT url from mytable WHERE keyword like '%{key}%'
```

I could use

```
Select url from mytable where keyword in ('key1', 'key2'...)
```

But I need to know which **url** is **associated** to every **keyword**. It seems MySQL doesn't support `table parameter` and executing the same statement 20K times is extremely slow.

What solution is suitable for this task?

Comment: What if you use in?

`Select url from mytable where keyword in ('key1', 'key2'...)`

Comment: @PrakharLondhe: I would loose the information about which key was associated to the returned rurls

Comment: maybe... if I write Select keyword, url from mytable where keyword in ('key1', 'key2'...) it would partially work. But how can I manage a list of like '%key%'?

Comment: ": I would loose the information about which key was associated to the returned rurls " - no. You get back a limited number of URL's. You can post-filter them to get the matching keyword. Basically select url and keyword and then filter again on the client to find out which keyword was hitting.

Comment: Is there any other solution like create a temporary table before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select url, keyword from mytable where keyword in ('key1', 'key2'...)
```

This way, you are getting both the URL AND its corresponding qualified keyword.  But not knowing more of your table, records, duplications, etc. you may get more records than you care to.

As for trying to go against 20k keywords to look for, you might want to build a secondary temp table and apply a JOIN to it.  Then you could do an insert of ex: 100 keywords at a time which would be quicker (or doing some bulk load option) and THEN query with a JOIN to this temporary table.

Finally, if multiple rows are possible, you may want

```
Select 
      url, 
      keyword,
      count(*) timesFound
   from 
      mytable 
   where 
      keyword in ('key1', 'key2'...) 
   group by
      url, 
      keyword
```